# What tools would enable a data streaming visualization dashboard with apache storm?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I get real time data from a server that I send to a Kafka cluster and process with apache storm.
I would now like to find a way to visualize the data processed by apache storm.
I can't really find a tool that would allow me to do such a thing. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: u mean, some sort of summary? It really depends on the data though

Comment: I process in storm data in JSON format, and I would like to be able to make curves, histograms, pie-charts, things like that to be able to bring an analysis on it

Comment: I know it is a key-value format, but it depends on the value you assigned to the key. Visualize a encoded image/ML features is different than visualize other info though... If you have already processed, cleaned  the data, you can plot on https://www.chartjs.org/ for java or matplotlib or plotly in python though

Comment: Do you mean that I can connect a bolt to a python program that would perform the visualization? 
Or do I have to create a bolt that saves the processed data in csv and then use python?

Comment: As Storm is designed more for distributed computation and not for visualization, I would recommend to use additional/external tools. You may check out Grafana or Graphite for real-time visualization. There are multiple ways how to connect these with Storm.

Comment: Grafana seems good, I'll try to use it

Answer (score 0):

As Storm is designed more for distributed computation and not for visualization, I would recommend to use additional/external tools.

You may check out **[Grafana](https://grafana.com/)** or **[Graphite](https://graphiteapp.org/)** for real-time visualization. However, there are multiple ways how to connect these with Apache Storm.